# How can I search emacs built-in manual?

Tags: emacs

In emacs `C-h i` opens the built-in help. One can then navigate through the different so-called nodes and learn everything. I could not learn one thing though; how can I **search** the manual?

As an example, say I want to find all the nodes that contains the word *agenda* in them - can I do it somehow?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `M-x emacs-index-search` to search for some keywords in the Emacs manual's index.

Answer (score 3):

Just press the key `s`:

> s searches Info documents
>
> The commands which move between and inside nodes allow you to read
>   the entire manual or its large portions. But what if you need to find
>   some information in the manual as fast as you can, and you don't know
>   or don't remember in what node to look for it? This need arises when
>   you use a manual as a reference, or when it is impractical to read the
>   entire manual before you start using the programs it describes.
>
> Info has powerful searching facilities that let you find things
>   quickly. You can search either the manual text or its indices.
>
> The s command allows you to search a whole Info file for a string. It
>   switches to the next node if and when that is necessary. You type s
>   followed by the string to search for, terminated by RET. To search
>   for the same string again, just s followed by RET will do. The
>   file's nodes are scanned in the order they are in the file, which has
>   no necessary relationship to the order that they may be in the tree
>   structure of menus and ‘next’ pointers. But normally the two orders
>   are not very different. In any case, you can always look at the mode
>   line to find out what node you have reached, if the header is not
>   visible (this can happen, because s puts your cursor at the occurrence
>   of the string, not at the beginning of the node).
>
> Instead of using s in Emacs Info and in the stand-alone Info, you can
>   use an incremental search started with C-s or C-r. It can search
>   through multiple Info nodes. See Incremental Search. In Emacs, you can
>   disable this behavior by setting the variable Info-isearch-search to
>   nil (see Emacs Info Variables).

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/info/Search-Text.html#Search-Text

More info:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/info/Advanced.html#Advanced

Comment: it seems like `s` doesn't work when I'm in the top-most level of `info` (where I see a long list of modes). So the question remains, how to search for something, while not knowing where it is actually defined.

Comment: You should at least know if it is in the emacs manual or the org manual, etc. If you don't then you can use `C-h F` (note the capital F) for commands and it jumps right to the relevant info page. Try it with `forward-char` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Info search does not search ***node names*** per se.  It will only find node-name matches if the same search string matches the title of the node or something else in the ***node text***.  The title is typically, but not always, the same as the node name. But searching this way typically means hitting zillions of other search hits throughout the manual.

Info command `g` (`Info-goto-node`) can help, because it matches only node names. But it can help here only if it provides *substring* or *regexp* matching. Ido mode will at least give you substring matching. But you can do better with *Icicles*.

[**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) command [`icicle-Info-goto-node`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Info_Enhancements) (`g` in Info when in *Icicle* mode) gives you matching directly against [node names, or node content, or both](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View#ThirdExampleNarrowingAManual).  It is a multi-command, so you can visit multiple nodes in the same command invocation.  Here is [more](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Isearch_Enhancements#ContentMatchingPatternAsIsearchRegexp) info about this.

(And yes, you must first choose a manual to search.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>i</kbd> to search the index of the manual, with tab completion.

You can also use interactive search, <kbd>C-s</kbd>.  It starts by searching in the current node, but if you type a search term and hit <kbd>C-s</kbd> again, it will search for that text in subsequent nodes as well.